# Error in decimal division result in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm going to do a little javascript operation on my HTML page.

I have no problem dividing 2 numbers by each other.

But if I get the same number from the html input section, the result is wrong.

**Sample**

```js
total = 99.90/1.08
```

The result of this operation **92.50** yes I want to find this result.

But when I get the number 99.90 from input in html

```js
total = input/1.08
```

The result is **91.66**

How can I fix this?

```js
function kdv_fiyat_1_1_i() {
    var kdv_fiyat_1_1;
    kdv = parseInt(document.getElementById('kdv').value);
    fiyat = parseInt(document.getElementById('fiyat_1_1').value);
            
    toplam = fiyat/1.08;
    kdv_fiyat_1_1 = toplam
    document.getElementById('fiyat_1_1').value = kdv_fiyat_1_1;
}
```

Comment: Because you’re using [`parseInt`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and are expecting a float… Please use `parseInt` [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead, or, specifically for `<input>`s, [`.valueAsNumber`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties).

Comment: @SebastianSimon you should post that as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: Can you make me a small example for this? I do not know how to do it. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @BYHK The documentation has small examples. Simply use `Number` instead of `parseInt`, or, even better, use a proper `<input type="number">` and use the `.valueAsNumber` property instead of `.value`. Then you don’t even need to convert this to a number, because, as the name implies, it already is a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
function kdv_fiyat_1_1_i(){
        var kdv_fiyat_1_1;
        kdv= parseInt(document.getElementById('kdv').value);
        fiyat= parseInt(document.getElementById('fiyat_1_1').value);
        
        toplam = fiyat/1.08;
        kdv_fiyat_1_1= toplam
        document.getElementById('fiyat_1_1').value = kdv_fiyat_1_1;
    }
```

Just changed few things and I think its should work just fine.
What I did is I removed the parseInt and instead added a **+ operator**, what this does is it converts the string to a Number, and yeah it pretty much does the job, if your logic was correct then you should get your desired output